# should I append the database GUID to filename?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, guid

I have a method which contains a file upload control. It uses the .saveas property to save the file to the physical location.

Then in my code I have a table adapter which inserts the file location to the database.
In the database a new GUID is created per new insert.

I would like to grab the GUID from the recently inserted row and append it to the start of the filename. Therefore do I let the method save the file, insert to the database and then rename the physical file with the GUID or is there another way ?

---

I am defining my GUID like this:

```
Guid GID = System.Guid.NewGuid();
```

Then i have this:

```
int FileUploadNew = FileUploadAdapter.InsertFileUpload(GID, path1);
```

The GUID column in the database is NVARCHAR (MAX)

Any ideas?

** Update **

fixed by using this: `string GID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();`

Comment: first add a row in db without filename, get the guid, save the file with guid in its name and then update the db with path after successful save. In case an error occurs you can always find orphan records without filename in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also you can create your own GUID and send it to database when saving the file 
Guid.NewGuid()

Comment: Would it be best to create the GUID in C# and then send it the DB in a text column? or would it be better using the NEWID() in SQL SERVER...?

Comment: In your case its better to create it your self because it decrease the round trip to sql, in your solution you should refer to sql twice but now you need just one time for insertion no read needed

Comment: should i call the column GUID? and make it plain text?

Comment: Welcome,thats why we are here

Comment: Please can you check my answer, running into some problems.